# build a dynamic JSON object from the MONGODB , create a .json file and save the object to it

Tags: json, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

Lets say we have our MongoDB and we want to backup the data into a .json file 
 example for an output file : `database.json` and inside :

```
    {
  "collections": [
    {"name": "admin"},
    {"name": "class"},
    {"name": "lesson"},
    {"name": "message"},
    {"name": "room"},
    {"name": "student"},
    {"name": "subject"},
    {"name": "teacher"}
  ],
  "subjects": [
    {
      "name": "Null",
      "color": "#FFFFFF"
    },
    {
      "name": "Design Art",
      "color": "#82B9D6"
    },
    {
      "name": "Plastic Art",
      "color": "#a3db05"
    },
    {
      "name": "Media And Production",
      "color": "#522a64"
    }, //...there is a continue to this file ....
 }
```

each collection should be added to the *collections* and for each collection there should be an array of all the info inside it (like above)

I'm using python 3.4 with the pymongo driver. 
What is the best way to get all the info from the DB , create the JSON object and insert it to a **new** .json file

Answer (score 0):

I found this way of doing it :

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint


def main():
    with open('../config/database.json') as database_config:
        config = json.load(database_config)

    client = MongoClient(config["mongodb"])
    db = client[config["database"]]
    data = dict()

    data["collections"] = db.collection_names()

    for collection_name in db.collection_names():
        data[collection_name] = get_collection(db, collection_name)
    pprint(data)
    insert_data_to_file(data)


def get_collection(db, collection_name):
    collection_list = []
    collection = db[collection_name]
    cursor = collection.find({})
    for document in cursor:
        _id = document.pop('_id')
        document['_id'] = str(_id)
        collection_list.append(document)
    return collection_list


def insert_data_to_file(data):
    with open('database.json', 'x') as database:
        json.dump(data, database, sort_keys=True)


main()
```